# How to peek at the remaining stringstream characters after using getline?

Tags: c++, getline, stringstream

```
std::string s;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "a=b+c" << std::endl << "d=e+f";

std::getline(ss, s, '=');   // gives me "a"
std::getline(ss, s);        /* gives me "b+c"  <- just want to peek: don't
                                                  want to change state of ss */
std::getline(ss, s, '+');   // BUT still want "b" here, not "d=e"
```

`s` now contains `"a"` Now, how do I **peek** at the remaining characters of the line (`"b+c"`)? That is, **without** causing the next operation to start at the next line?

(Example contrived, I know.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can revert the stringstream using istream::seekg() like this:

```
ss.seekg(ss.beg);
```

Then you can read it all over again. This is better than creating a new one, as it saves memory, and is a tiny bit faster.

Comment: Thanks - looks promising. If I don't want to start `seekg` from the beginning, how can I get the current position of a stringstream (so I can store that position and `seekg` to it later)?

Comment: I believe that you can use ```ss.cur```, but I am not 100% sure. Try it :)

Comment: No, doesn't appear so. Shows 1 even after using a `getline` which should have taken a good chunk off.

Comment: I'm not too sure then. I can't stay to help, so try googling around ;)

Comment: You can use `tellg()` to get the current position. Do this before the read. Then you can move back to it after the read. Alternatively you can use `seekg()` to move relative to the current position. `seekg(-s.size(), std::ios_base::cur)`

Comment: @LokiAstari - thanks, nearly there. The only problem is that `seekg()` doesn't appear to work once a linefeed is encountered. So `seekg` works fine with `getline(ss, s, '+')` but not `getline(ss, s)`

Comment: @MiloChen: don't belive that. New line is not special in any way. See my answer below.

Comment: @LokiAstari - hmm was trying out at http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp_online.php. I have posted test code at: http://ideone.com/7lkUhG which gives a different answer (output `b`) with compileonline (outputs `b+c`). Odd... (There's no permalink at compileonline so you'll just have to copy and paste from ideone)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
std::getline(ss, s, '=');                     // gives me "a"
std::getline(ss, s);                          // gives me "b+c"
ss.seekg(-(s.size()+1) ,std::ios_base::cur);  // Roll back
                                              // Need to +1 becuase we throw away a character
                                              // with std::getline() that is not in the string.

std::getline(ss, s, '+');                     // gives me "b"
```

The problem with the above is that std::getline() will throw away a '\n' if it finds it before eof. but if it finds eof first then we have a problem as the +1 puts us in the wrong place. So it works for the above example but it will fail for the last line unless you gurantee that every line is terminated by '\n'

So we can use tellg() if you can't provide that gurantee:

```
std::getline(ss, s, '=');                     // gives me "a"
std::streampos  save = ss.tellg(); 
std::getline(ss, s);                          // gives me "b+c"
ss.seekg(save);                               // Roll back


std::getline(ss, s, '+');                     // gives me "b"
```

Comment: Yep… `tellg` is the only way to go, or use binary mode.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Or we could try: `ss.seekg(-(s.size()+ (ss?1:0)) ,std::ios_base::cur);` Probably have to reset some flags at the same time. But that will be true for the `tellg()` version as well.

Answer (score 1):

You would either need to make a new `stringstream` from `s` after:

```
std::getline(ss, s);        // gives me "b+c"
std::stringstream ss2(s);
std::getline(ss2,s, '+');   // will give b and maintain position in original ss
```

Or use the following instead:

```
std::getline(ss, s, '+');   // will give b
```

Edit: second option changes state of ss, so does not fit your editted criterion.

Comment: What about instead of `peek`ing at the remaining *line* (`"b+c"`), I peek at the remaining *string* (`"b+c\nd=e+f"`)? Would that be easier? I was hoping that there would be some buffer member which held all the remaining characters.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution for your problem would be to use another `std::stringstream` for `s`:

```
std::getline(ss, s, '='); // get "a"
std::getline(ss, s);

std::stringstream ss2(s); // create a stringstream with "b+c"
std::getline(ss2, s, '+'); // gets "b"
```

**Edit:** Then again, why are you reading `"b+c"` instead of just getting `"b"` first then `"c"`? (I don't know about your implementation)

Comment: Thanks - how would I take a `peek` at the entire remaining string within the ss?

Comment: I deleted my comment when I realized that peek gets a single character and may not be fit. Not sure though.

Comment: What about instead of `peek`ing at the remaining *line* (`"b+c"`), I peek at the remaining *string* (`"b+c\nd=e+f"`)? Would that be easier? I was hoping that there would be some buffer member which held all the remaining characters.

Comment: I did a few tests with ideone and my conclusion is that peeking from an `std::stringstream` will peek from the remaining buffer. Unfortunately, you can only get one character, so that solution is not really the best. In fact, it's bad ;_;